# Why does Chewbacca’s bowcaster fire red projectiles?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Chewbacca’s bowcaster is firing red projectiles in Episode VII. As far as I can remember from movies, shows and games bowcasters only fire green projectiles.

[image]

<sup>A Wookiee firing a green projectile from a bowcaster in *Star Wars: Episode III* (at about 50 minutes)</sup>

Why does Chewbacca’s bowcaster fire red projectiles in *The Force Awakens*? Is there more information about this bowcaster? Have there been others that I did not notice?

A related question: [Why was Han Solo acting like he’s never seen Chewbacca’s bowcaster before?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111723/22898)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Your underlying premise is incorrect. In *The Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi*, Chewbacca's bowcaster fires red bolts, not green. Bowcasters have been depicted in most of the video games as green. The depiction in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* appears consistent with the weapon's previous appearances.

[image: Chewbacca firing a red bowcaster bolt on the Forest Moon]

> Most sources, including *Revenge of the Sith*, depict bowcasters firing green bolts. However, in *The Empire Strikes Back* and *Return of the Jedi*, Chewbacca's weapon fires red bolts and in *Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds*, Chewbacca's weapon fires yellow bolts. This is due to the retcon that Chewbacca made his out of a stormtrooper rifle.
>
> **Wookieepedia: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bowcaster/Legends**

While this is data from a non-canon source, the previous depictions in film ARE canon and confirm this would not be deviating from the source materials in any way.

In this return of the Jedi supercut, Chewbacca is seen on Endor shooting his bowcaster with a red bolt clearly visible. (at 4:40)

Comment: Wow, I planned looking through IV-VI again and found the scene at 58:22. I'm not sure if I would have caught that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because Chewbacca's bowcaster was made from Imperial blaster components. The crystal inside is from an Imperial blaster, so it shoots red projectiles.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to confirm this assertion?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Star_Wars mentions it was made from a Stormtrooper rifle.